# PHP from 5.6 to 7.2 advice

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result()

I am having some issues migrating old code from Php 5.6 to 8 (I know, I'm late !).
The initial code was:

```
$datama=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as TOTALFOUNDA FROM errorlog WHERE IP ='$ff' and datenow>'$last' and counting='3'"); 
$anymatchesa=mysql_result($datama,0,"TOTALFOUNDA");
```

And I came up with this (the connexion to the DB with $conx is OK) :

```
$datama=mysqli_query($conx,"SELECT COUNT(*) as TOTALFOUNDA FROM errorlog WHERE IP ='$ff' and datenow>'$last' and counting='3'"); 
$anymatchesa=mysqli_result($datama,0,"TOTALFOUNDA");
```

But I get an error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result()...

Comment: You can upgrade straight to PHP 8.1. Why change one outdated version for another?

Comment: You may want to refer to [PHP: Supported Versions](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).